# Can I choose where an attachment appears in an email using ActionMailer in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, actionmailer, email-attachments

I have the following statement in my mailer for one of my emails being sent.

```
attachments.inline['eBookSample.pdf'] = File.read('app/assets/images/eBookSample.pdf')
```

Normally the PDF documents have appeared at the bottom of the email which was by design. However for one of my email I would like to select where the PDF attachment appears in the email.

I know about the `image_tag` attachments statement that you can use for images.

```
<%= image_tag attachments['image.jpg'].url %>
```

Does something similar exist for documents where where I can position a PDF attachment in the email?

Answer (score 2):

There are incredibly few mail systems which allow you to insert non-image attachments into the e-mail body. *IBM Lotus* is the only one that I personally have knowledge of.

For this reason, nobody bothered adding this functionality to `ActionMailer`.

Attempting to render a PDF file inside the e-mail's body will yield the actual bytes that make up that file. It won't be a nice view.

I'm suggesting the following workaround:

- Add the non-image attachments as regular attachments. They will
  show up at the end of the file, in GMail, or in the "Attached" bar,
  in Outlook.
- In the e-mail body, add hyperlinks to copies of those attachments. These copies will of course need to be stored on your server, and be
  accessible online.